# Highcharts border around legend symbol

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to add a ***border*** to a highcharts ***legend symbol*** (in particular for bar or column charts).  Notice how in this picture the border color of the bar doesn't match the border color of the legend symbol.  I noticed that it's a [current feature request](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2450962-customising-legend-symbols), and the author seemed to have a workaround for border ***radius*** that involved modifying the highcharts js file.  I'm not going to modify the highcharts library, but I'm willing to do a little hackery dynamically.

[image: Notice how the border color of the bar doesn't match the border color of the legend symbol]

Comment: Another possible option is to remove the border from your bars. That way they look the same.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a great option for us in our current situation, but it is a good idea in general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbol-outline with pie chart -or- custom legend symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201607/symbol-outline-with-pie-chart-or-custom-legend-symbols)

Comment: @AlexMA see the linked question above.  It's a hack but I believe gets you want you want.

Comment: You're right!  Thanks.  Might even use that solution.  Voted to close.